# is this is a right way to update MySQL table with specific time period

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating my MySQL table with specific time. What actually happening is - payment status is unpaid and it will automatic cancel after 15 mins. but only specific payment status, who is older than 15 mins should be cancel.

i am trying to update mysql table entry only in specific time like 15 min.

```
$sql = "UPDATE payers SET payment_status='Cancel' WHERE 
payment_status=unpaid >= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE"; 
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){ 
echo "Record was updated successfully."; 
} else { 
echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. "  
. mysqli_error($conn); 
}  
mysqli_close($$conn);
```

payment_status need to update only when unpaid is older than 15 mins.

Comment: What do you mean by "unpaid is older than 15 mins"? How do you know how old is "unpaid"?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

This SQL should work for you:

```
UPDATE payers
SET payment_status='Cancel'
WHERE payment_status='unpaid'
  AND payment_time <= NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
```

However, this has hidden problem: what if someone pays exactly after 15 min of order submission? They would have paid, but you wouldn't send them your goods.

Comment: Thanks for reply buddy, and answer for this line - but you wouldn't send them your goods.  that unpaid invoice expired from payment gatway system. and they dont give such IPN request back for same. so i am doing it by database.

Comment: can you tell me is payment_time is a column name?

Comment: You should have such column. If you don't, there is no way to tell if order has expired. Regarding 15 min, it has very small probability of customer placing an order exactly as you are expiring it.

Comment: is the payment_time column should be datetime datatype column.